# Conditionally set a context in Watson Conversation

Tags: json, conditional-statements, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm using Watson Conversation and trying to conditionally set a context variable.

In response to a question we ask, some people say "yes," some say "no," and some say "no, but my husband has" (or some similar variations). I have the entity @other_person that recognizes "husband" (and wife, and friend, etc).

What I'm trying to do is set a context variable $mentionother to true if they mention another person, and false otherwise.
So far I have this, but it's not working and I can't quite figure it out. I haven't been able to find good documentation on this so I may be way off.

```
"context": {
  "mentionother": "(@other_person==null ? false : true)"
}
```

Can anyone provide some help here, and/or tell me where to look for better documentation on this?
I'm actually not 100% sure what language to look under; I think I've read this is Java but I'm out of practice so not positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional variables work like this:

variable x = (expression) ? value if true : value if false

try this:
"(@other_person==null)? false : true"

since you are not sure what you are using next to json i'm not 100% positive this works.

source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This unfortunately spits out the whole thing in between the quotes as a string

Answer (score 2):

In this case, @R. Timmer is correct. But you need to set the condition inside the `<? ?>`, so, is basically this:

```
{
  "context": {
    "otherPerson": "<? (@other_person==null)? false : true ?>"
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Now you can see $otherPerson true or false"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

Please, consider marking the answer for R. Timmer, I just supplemented his answer.